# Getting session values from extern file

Tags: php, ajax

i have two files one extern file menu_filter_enigne.php where i post values via ajax and store them into session

```
   session_start();

   $active_menu_item = $_POST['active'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['activeItems'])) {
       $_SESSION['activeItems'] = array();     }

   if(!in_array($active_menu_item, $_SESSION['activeItems'])) {
       $_SESSION['activeItems'][] = $active_menu_item;
   }
```

how i can get the session value to my other php files? (In next step i want to ajax reload one div, this script i already have and works fine co when i acomplish to get stored session value i will refresh via ajax only some divs when i get the session value is is possible)

Comment: Use `session_start()` and initialize the session the same way?

Answer (score 0):

To get a value previously loaded in session in one script from another, you can do this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $activeItems = $_SESSION['activeItems'];
    // ...
```

Notice `session_start()` is at the top, before any output.  Calling this method will load the user's session data into the `$_SESSION` superglobal and will be available even during AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same:

```
<?
session_start();


$var=$_SESSION['activeItems'];

?>
```